# How to diagnose why Grub won't boot a Windows partition?

Tags: linux, boot, grub, grub2, boot-loader

I just imaged a Windows partition onto a new drive with dd. Then I changed the NTFS UUID to a new one. Then I ran update-grub (using grub2) and restarted.

Now there is a new menu entry in the Grub menu corresponding to my new cloned drive - but when I boot it, it boots the original windows drive!

I have checked that the drive path (/dev/sdd1) and the volume UUID are correct in the new grub.cfg.

Do you know where I can find some logs or anything indicating what is wrong with my drive clone, and why Grub seems is booting the original Windows drive instead?

Thanks, Louise

Comment: Did you change anything on the Windows boot loader? This is chain-loading, so winboot is probably still pointing to the original volume path.

Comment: Thanks! No, I didn't change anything to do with the Windows bootloader. I just updated the voume UUID and ran sudo update-grub. Do you know how I can change the bootloader to point to the new disk?

Comment: Yeah, you need to boot a Windows installer and use `bootrec` on the command line or use `ms-sys` in Linux. I'm not at a computer, or I'd give you the man pages and all that. Just google these things, as either will manipulate the Windows bootloader fine.

Comment: Hi @SmallLoanOf1M, I've rebuilt the MBR using ms-sys, LILO and a Windows tool (MiniTool Partition Wizard) and the new GRUB entry still boots my old Windows drive! I've looked in the GRUB configuration file and everything seems right - hints, drive letters and UUID all point to the new partition. Can you think of any way to see what's going on? I think GRUB must be falling back on the old drive for some reason...